# How to call API in Django views

Tags: django

I wanted to call the API in Django views and want to render into html template but I couldn't able to pass the API.I have tried in this way

I'm rendering the template using "table_data" which contains the endpoint data which contains the tables.

I'm rendering it in the html using the loop but in views I'm not able to get the API data I don't even see an error as well. How could I able to implement it

views.py

```
    def homeview(request):
        userbase = Userbase.objects.all()
        table_data= requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:1500/api/').json() 
        if request.method == 'POST':
           
            userb = Userbase()
            userb.company_code =  request.POST.get('company_code')
            userb.Area =  request.POST.get('area')
            userb.country =  request.POST.get('country')
            userb.From_Date = request.POST.get('from_Date')
            userb.To_Date = request.POST.get('to_Date')
            userb.Predicted_Paid_days =  
                      request.POST.get('Predicted_Paid_days')
            userb.PBK_Desc =  request.POST.get('PBK_Desc')
            userb.Vendor_Name =  request.POST.get('Vendor_Name')
            userb.Reference =  request.POST.get('Reference')
            userb.Payment_Term =  request.POST.get('Payment_Term')
            userb.save()
        
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'userbase':userbase, 
 'table_data':table_data})
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'table_data':table_data})
```

html:

```
<table class="table" id='table_id'>
          <thead>
            <thead id="tablehead">
              <tr>
                <th>Stage</th>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th> Area </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

          <tbody>

            {% for list in table_data %}
            <tr >
              <td>{{list.stage }}</td>
              <td>{{list.region }} </td>
              <td>{{list.area}}</td>
            </tr>
           {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue, are you getting an error? What does table_data contain and how are you using it in your template?

Comment: I'm rendering the template using table_data which contains the endpoint data. table_data which contains the tables  and I'm rendering it in the html using the loop but in views I'm going wrong

Comment: Can you add the relevant section of your template and some example 'table_data' to your question

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Can you add the contents of `table_data` or the response from the API? Can be truncated if it's too large

Comment: though table data which have around 24+ columns and 20rows

Comment: Can you just share the response up to the end of the first row? What does `print(type(table_data))` output? Without knowing what `table_data` contains it's hard to know where you might be going wrong

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p4gxtvy8/ pls check it here

Comment: as it s showing type as <class 'list'>

Comment: That's the output from `print(table_data)`? Everything looks fine from the data and code, the only thing left is the template. Is that definitely the template `home.html` and can you share the full template?

Comment: I have issue with views actually .http://jsfiddle.net/p4gxtvy8/1/ I have added html as well

Comment: You table is wrapped with `{% if userb %}` but you don't have `userb` in your context? Also your `endfor` should be after `</tr>`

Comment: I have tried adding it userb in my view as well still no luck.

Comment: You and `userbase` in your context on a POST using a variable of the same name but that variable doesn't exist, is this your error? Should you be adding `userb` to the context instead?

Comment: yeah I have included userb to  the context and also I have tried another method to call api it works but tats not the way i want to achieve it  I have added another working views to call api. http://jsfiddle.net/v09be185/

Comment: Your working view adds `userb` to the context and the broken one adds `userbase`, your `if` in the template uses `userb`

Comment: Thanks mate. I didn't looked it. its working now. Is it possible to filter the API without saving in the database in Django. or do I have to use JS.

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue. You could filter `table_data` in your view though maybe this should be another question